# moment.js on a nodeJS application - correct timezone, wrong date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

This seems like a really simple question but I can't find a way to work it out.

My goal is simple, I wan't `moment()` to return local time with the correct offset.

I'm doing the following:

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Singapore');
console.log(moment());
```

and the result is `Thu Nov 30 2017 05:54:53 GMT+0000 (ASIA)`, which has the correct timezone, but offset is still UTC.

I've tried restarting the node process but with no luck.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a local flag for moment to get local times instead with `moment().local()`. From the original documentation:

```
var a = moment.utc([2011, 0, 1, 8]);
a.hours(); // 8 UTC
a.local();
a.hours(); // 0 PST
```

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/